# Variable error in Python

Tags: python, variables

I'm in a Python course and can't figure out why my code won't work:

```py
import os
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\prank")

for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
rename_files()
```

The code above returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/renamepy.py", line 5, in <module>
    for file_name in file_list:
NameError: name 'file_list' is not defined
>>>
```

Why `file_name` is not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk-through your code:

```
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\prank")
```

In you `rename_files()` function, you have defined a function that returns nothing. You have set a local scoped `file_list` that will be released and cannot be accessed once you're outside the function.

```
for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
rename_files()
```

Then when you're outside of the `rename_files()` function, you try to access a `file_list` that has not previously been initialized in the for-loop, so it throws the `NameError`

```
NameError: name 'file_list' is not defined
```

And then you called the `rename_files()` function but still `file_list` will not exist outside of the function.

There's several ways to ensure that `file_list` is materialized before you go through the for-loop.

**Solution 1**: Use the global variable.

```
file_list = []

def rename_files():
    global file_list
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\prank")
rename_files()
for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
```

**Solution 2**: take the `file_list` initialization outside of the function.

```
file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\prank")
for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
```

**Solution 3** (as suggested by Karin): Put the for-loop into the function:

```
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\prank")
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
```

Note: this is similar to Solution 2 since they are trying to put both the `file_list` initialization and the for-loop under the same scope.

Comment: Thank you! I am used to brackets. I didn't know indentation defines the scope!

Answer (score 2):

This is an indentation error. Your `for` loop is outside of the scope of `rename_files()` since it was not indented. It should be:

```
import os
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\prank")

    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))

rename_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your for loop so its within the body of your `rename_file` function:

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\prank")

    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))

rename_files()
```

As `file_list` is only in scope within the method.